# Saving files to a S3 bucket with a directory structure, in .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, f#

I am trying to save files to a S3 bucket using the *AWSSDK.S3* nuget package.
My code is in F#, but answers in C# would work too.

I have a series of files I want to organize by folder. From what I understand, there is not really a folder structure in the S3 buckets, but folders are rather 'keys' which are part of the filename. I could be wrong, but that's my understanding at this point.

The code is taking crypto coin data and making one file a day, per coin. This was working until I wanted to make one folder per coin.

Filenames have the following format: "coinname-YYMMDD.csv', for example: "BTCUSDT-20200820.csv'.
and I want a structure like:

```
coin1/
    coin1-20200819.csv
    coin1-20200820.csv
coin2/
    coin2-20200819.csv
    coin2-20200820.csv
```

From the documentation, I need to set the folder as a 'key', so here is the code:

```
// upload a file
let uploadFile (filename: string) =

    // create the key
    let coinName = Path.GetFileName(filename).Split('-').[0]
    let keyName  = Path.Combine(coinName, filename)

    // create the send request
    let putObjectRequest = Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest()
    putObjectRequest.FilePath     <- filename
    putObjectRequest.Key          <- keyName
    putObjectRequest.BucketName   <- bucketName
    putObjectRequest.CannedACL    <- S3CannedACL.PublicRead
    putObjectRequest.StorageClass <- S3StorageClass.IntelligentTiering
    putObjectRequest.ContentType  <- "text/csv"

    // send the object
    let response =
        s3client.PutObjectAsync(putObjectRequest)
        |> Async.AwaitTask
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

    // DEBUG OUTPUT
    printfn "trying to save %s" keyName
    printfn "object request: %s" (putObjectRequest |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject)
    printfn "response: %s" (response |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject)

    // handle the response
    match response.HttpStatusCode with
    | HttpStatusCode.OK -> Ok()
    | _                 -> let message = sprintf "error uploading file %s to S3: %s" filename (response.ToString())
                           Error(message)
```

The debug output shows this:

> trying to save /app/leechdata/ATOMUSDT/ATOMUSDT-20200819.csv object
> request:
> {"CannedACL":{"Value":"public-read"},"InputStream":null,"FilePath":"/app/leechdata/ATOMUSDT/ATOMUSDT-20200819.csv","ContentBody":null,"AutoCloseStream":true,"AutoResetStreamPosition":true,"UseChunkEncoding":true,"BucketName":"sunnybot-cap
> ture","Headers":{"Count":1,"Keys":["Content-Type"],"CacheControl":null,"ContentDisposition":null,"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentLength":-1,"ContentMD5":null,"ContentType":"text/csv","ExpiresUtc":null,"Expires":null},"Metadata":{"Count":0,"Keys":[]},"Key"
> :"/app/leechdata/ATOMUSDT/ATOMUSDT-20200819.csv","ServerSideEncryptionMethod":null,"ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod":null,"ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey":null,"ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKeyMD5":null,"ServerSideEncryptionKeyManageme
> ntServiceKeyId":null,"ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceEncryptionContext":null,"StorageClass":{"Value":"INTELLIGENT_TIERING"},"ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus":null,"ObjectLockMode":null,"ObjectLockRetainUntilDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","WebsiteRedirect
> Location":null,"StreamTransferProgress":null,"ContentType":"text/csv","MD5Digest":null,"RequestPayer":null,"TagSet":[],"Grants":[]}
> response:
> {"Expiration":null,"ServerSideEncryptionMethod":null,"ETag":""6a614845e94ffa3fc1bfb8aad40bdb5b"","VersionId":null,"ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId":null,"ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod":null,"ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProv
> idedKeyMD5":null,"ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceEncryptionContext":null,"RequestCharged":null,"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"81892F3E28F07562","Metadata":{"x-amz-id-2":"/mTevk7iATTIKlvIs6eGGc3QK9+rHdzgPu6SzZ36eNfEzyjOS2BjXnEazTchL6z8P9kqU+eZJ
> N8="}},"ContentLength":0,"HttpStatusCode":200}

so, it looks like everything is fine, but the files do not appear!
if I don't specify the *Key* field, all the files get properly uploaded, without a folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't put a leading '/' in the key name, and the examples I've seen also don't have it.

Comment: but the /app/leechdata is not part of the filename itself, it's the path to get to the data; My understanding is that the filename is the key, am I wrong there? otherwise, how would you provide access to a file without uploading the whole path? it just takes the filename from the path. When I try to override that by adding a key with mypath/filename it is where it fails

Comment: The key is the name of the file as it appears once it's uploaded. If the key has a path separator, then everything but the final part is treated like a folder. So that's what goes into the Key property. The FilePath property is the local path to the actual file that's going to be uploaded (it may look completely different).

Comment: so that's exactly what I tried to do. And it returns me 'ok' and files are not there. While if I upload them without setting the key, they appear.

Comment: I don't know why you would get a 200 and not see the files, that is definitely strange. If you eliminate the leading '/' in the key name, per my original suggestion, do you get the same result? (So, key name would be "app/leechdata/ATOMUSDT/ATOMUSDT-20200819.csv").

Comment: @JimFoye, I think you saw the problem I couldn't see. I thought I had no leading '/' in the key name but I was putting in the whole filename, including the path with the leading '/' instead of using the actual name of the file! I thought I was getting the result of the Path.GerFilename call, but it wasn't the case. Yes, it works now!

Comment: so, I found why I was getting 200 as a feedback: the files were properly uploaded but under a folder without a name! it looked like that: https://imgur.com/a/liQGQVk

Comment: Yeah I thought that might be the case, they were there but not where expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload files to S3, I suggest to use `TransferUtility`, your key should contain both "folder" and "filename", e.g. `coin1/coin1-20200819.csv`. The `TransferUtility.UploadAsync` method would take 3 arguments:

- Path to your file, e.g. `@"C:\coin1-20200819.csv"`
- bucket name in your aws, e.g. `crypto`
- key name including folder in bucket and filename, e.g. `"coin1/coin1-20200819.csv"`
  Your code to upload a file would be something like this

```
let fileTransferUtil = new TransferUtility( s3client )  // create a transfer utility
fileTransferUtil.UploadAsync(@"C:\coin1-20200819.csv", "crypto", "coin1/coin1-20200819.csv" ) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: while I fixed the problem above with the suggestions from Jim, your solution is much simpler and I decided to go with it. thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Mark his answer is useful

Comment: What do you mean?